# Limit Dots on slick-slider (No jQuery)

Tags: javascript, css, animation, jsx, slick.js

If my slider contains more than 30-40 images the dots keep adding up forming multiple lines. My goal is to get something like the instagram dot navigation. Where you click on a dot and you receive the correct image while the active newly activated dot slides in the middle.

I know slick-slider has the option to select the slidesToScroll to divide the images in (blocks to scroll instead 1 by 1) which in fact can reduce your dots but doesn't help on mobile.

jQuery is not included in the Project so I would like to see some JS or JSX results for this request.

This is an example for what I want

https://codepen.io/nazarkomar/pen/RdRjqJ

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var slider = $('.main-slider');

    slider.slick({
        dots: true
    });

    function loadSliderDotClasses(stickSlider) {

        var dot = stickSlider.find('.slick-dots li.slick-active'),
        dotSize1 = 'dot-size-1',
        dotSize2 = 'dot-size-2',
        dotSize3 = 'dot-size-3';

        stickSlider.find('.slick-dots li').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass(dotSize1).removeClass(dotSize2).removeClass(dotSize3);
        });

        dot.prev().prev().prev().addClass(dotSize1);
        dot.prev().prev().addClass(dotSize2);
        dot.prev().addClass(dotSize3);
        dot.next().addClass(dotSize3);
        dot.next().next().addClass(dotSize2);
        dot.next().next().next().addClass(dotSize1);
    }

    loadSliderDotClasses(slider);

    slider.find('.slick-dots li').on('click', function() {
        loadSliderDotClasses(slider);
    });

    slider.on('swipe', function(event, slick, direction){
        loadSliderDotClasses(slider);
    });
});
```

https://codepen.io/nazarkomar/pen/RdRjqJ

Is it possible to translate this to JavaScript?

Comment: Of course it's possibleslie, jQuery is just JavaScript. But I've only ever seen Slick with a jQuery dependency. The one you're using doesn't require jQuery? Can you link it in your question?

Comment: @emsoff with Yarn / NPM. Yeah i thought the same.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://codepen.io/jboneca/pen/LYpLYdV) is the closest I can get without spending real time on it. Basically, all you need is a few vanilla JavaScript replacements for the jQuery. This should be enough to get you started.

1. Replace `$(element).remove()` and `$(element).add()` with `classList` alternative
2. Detecting the `.slick-active` node's index with `Array.from(element.parentNode.children).indexOf(element)`
3. Looping through the `.slick-dots li` element array to apply classes selectively, depending the relation of each to the active dot's index.

Answer (score 0):

One way to limit the number of dots visible in the viewport is by using the javascript `scrollIntoView` method. You will need to attach an `afterChange` event handler to the slick carousel.

```
var carousel = $('.carousel').slick(settings);

carousel.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
  var activeDotEl = $(event.target).find('.slick-dots').find('li.slick-active');
  activeDotEl.get(0).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'center' });
});
```

**codepen:** https://codepen.io/ahmu83/pen/vYbaRzQ

This is a CSS solution: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1799#issuecomment-147077244